# How to upload files to a page using razor jivescript/c#

Tags: javascript, c#

in my post, when clicking the create button it doesn't save the file I uploaded and it still shows the error Unable to access this site

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Inicio,Vencimento,ImovelId,LocatarioId,Ativo,ContratoPdf")] Contratos contratos, IFormFile arquivo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (arquivo != null && arquivo.Length > 0)
            {
                string diretorioDestino = @"C:\Code\Razor Pages\LRAdministra\LRAdministra\Arquivo";
                if (!Directory.Exists(diretorioDestino))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(diretorioDestino);
                }
                string nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(arquivo.FileName);
                string caminhoCompleto = Path.Combine(diretorioDestino, nomeArquivo);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(caminhoCompleto, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await arquivo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                contratos.ContratoPdf = nomeArquivo;
            }
```

Comment: "jivescript"???

Comment: yes, but my controller is in C#